# parsing XML with namespace in python 3 gives no data

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-namespaces

I have a XML with 3 namespaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cus:Customizations xmlns:cus="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/customizations" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xt="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/xmltypes">
  <cus:customization xsi:type="cus:EnvValueCustomizationType">
    <cus:description/>
    <cus:envValueAssignments>
      <xt:envValueType>working manager</xt:envValueType>
      <xt:location xsi:nil="true"/>
      <xt:owner>
        <xt:type>FLOW</xt:type>
        <xt:path>/somedir/dir/somepath3</xt:path>
      </xt:owner>
      <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
    </cus:envValueAssignments>
  </cus:customization>
  <cus:customization xsi:type="cus:FindAndReplaceCustomizationType">
    <cus:description/>
    <cus:query>
      <xt:resourceTypes>ProxyService</xt:resourceTypes>
      <xt:resourceTypes>SMTPServer</xt:resourceTypes>
          <xt:resourceTypes>SSconection</xt:resourceTypes>
      <xt:refsToSearch xsi:type="xt:ResourceRefType">
        <xt:type>FLOW</xt:type>
        <xt:path>/somedir/dir/somepath2</xt:path>
          </xt:refsToSearch>
      <xt:includeOnlyModifiedResources>false</xt:includeOnlyModifiedResources>
      <xt:searchString>Search String</xt:searchString>
      <xt:isCompleteMatch>false</xt:isCompleteMatch>
    </cus:query>
    <cus:replacement>Replacement String</cus:replacement>
  </cus:customization>
  <cus:customization xsi:type="cus:ReferenceCustomizationType">
    <cus:description/>
    <cus:refsToBeConsidered xsi:type="xt:ResourceRefType">
      <xt:type>FLOW</xt:type>
      <xt:path>/somedir/dir/somepath</xt:path>
    </cus:refsToBeConsidered>
        <cus:refsToBeConsidered xsi:type="xt:ResourceRefType">
      <xt:type>WSDL</xt:type>
      <xt:path>/somedir/dir/somepath</xt:path>
    </cus:refsToBeConsidered>
    <cus:refsToBeConsidered xsi:type="xt:ResourceRefType">
      <xt:type>ProxyService</xt:type>
      <xt:path>/somedir/dir/somepath</xt:path>
    </cus:refsToBeConsidered>
    <cus:externalReferenceMap>
      <xt:oldRef>
        <xt:type>FLOW</xt:type>
        <xt:path>/somedir/dir/somepath</xt:path>
      </xt:oldRef>
      <xt:newRef>
        <xt:type>FLOW</xt:type>
        <xt:path>/somedir/dir/somepath</xt:path>
      </xt:newRef>
        </cus:externalReferenceMap>
    <cus:externalReferenceMap>
      <xt:oldRef>
        <xt:type>XMLSchema</xt:type>
        <xt:path>/somedir/dir/somepath</xt:path>
      </xt:oldRef>
      <xt:newRef>
        <xt:type>XMLSchema</xt:type>
        <xt:path>/somedir/dir/somepath</xt:path>
      </xt:newRef>
    </cus:externalReferenceMap>
    <cus:externalReferenceMap>
      <xt:oldRef>
        <xt:type>XMLSchema</xt:type>
        <xt:path>/somedir/dir/somepath</xt:path>
      </xt:oldRef>
      <xt:newRef>
        <xt:type>XMLSchema</xt:type>
        <xt:path>/somedir/dir/somepath</xt:path>
      </xt:newRef>
    </cus:externalReferenceMap>
  </cus:customization>
</cus:Customizations>
```

I am using lxml in python 3 but I am getting empty data. when I print the root it gives me root tag.
here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os
import os.path
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import lxml.etree

times = []
keys = []
tree2 = lxml.etree.parse('/home/vagrant/dev_dir/ALSBCustomizationFile.xml')
NSMAP = {'cus': 'http://www.bea.com/wli/config/customizations',
         'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
         'xt': 'http://www.bea.com/wli/config/xmltypes'}

root22 = tree2.getroot()

print(root22)
namespace = root22.findall('cus:Customizations', NSMAP)
namespace2 = root22.findall('xsi:customization', NSMAP)
namespace3 = root22.findall('xt:envValueType', NSMAP)

print(namespace3)
```

when I run this script I get below output.

```
<Element {http://www.bea.com/wli/config/customizations}Customizations at 0x7faadb3a0508>
[]
```

I am able to get the root tag, but not able to access the inner namespace tags.

Can you please help where I am going wrong. how do I read the data in all the inner namespace tags.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's becuase the target element you're trying to get is not direct child of the root element. You need to either specify full path from root to the target element :

```
namespace3 = root22.findall('cus:customization/cus:envValueAssignments/xt:envValueType', NSMAP)
```

or using relative descendant-or-self axis (`.//`) at the beginning of the XPath :

```
namespace3 = root22.findall('.//xt:envValueType', NSMAP)
```

For executing more complex XPath expression later you better off using `lxml`'s `xpath()` method which provide better XPath support :

```
namespace3 = root22.xpath('.//xt:envValueType', namespaces=NSMAP)
```